# Facebook parse by php

Tags: php, facebook, parsing

I'm trying to parse Facebook. For example I try to get amount of likes from this post:
https://www.facebook.com/nba/posts/10152580221833463. I know that it need to do with Graph API, but my question - is it possible to parse Facebook pages by phpQuery for example, or maybe by another library?
I parsed websites by phpQuery a lot of times. But here I stumbled upon a wall.
I get the page with curl but when I try to work with it by phpQuery - I can't get any data by selectors. When I look what I have in my object phpQuery I see that there are no any html and text - only js code which generate html.
Is that I'm trying to do - impossible? Perhaps I should not waste time?

Comment: fb generates html via js, so you have to parse js to find it, and hope it's not an ajax query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex by matching this pattern **"likecount":(\d+),**

```
<?php

$pattern = '/"likecount":(\d+),/';

if (preg_match($pattern, $page_content, $match)) {
  $likes = $match[1];
}

?>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://ideone.com/zLxUXS).

Be aware that this is a bad behaviour and you should use the [official API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/object/likes) if you don't want your script to break any time soon.